# What is the best way two keep two Sitecore CM instance in Azure

Tags: sitecore-client, azure, scaling

We are getting so many requests at time and  this is causing Sitecore slowness and unresponsive.
We have decided to go with multiple CM instance.

Please suggest what are the best approaches to complete two Sitecore CM instances.

For me information we are using Sitecore version 9.0.1.

Comment: Documentation right here: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/scaling-and-configuring-content-management.html - can honestly say, in 13 years of implementing Sitecore, I've never had to do this. There are better ways to improve CM performance.

Comment: How many requests? How many concurrent users?

Answer (score 1):

Before jumping straight into scaling out and adding more cm instances, I would recommend following some basic tuning guidelines first.

This guide is quite old but still relevant:
https://doc.sitecore.com/legacy-docs/SC71/cms-tuning-guide-sc70-72-a4.pdf

We have several hundred content authors and frequently drop down to one CM instance with out any issue.

As long as you have a sufficiently specced machine, running with well tuned caches then you should be ok.

What spec is available for your first CM instance? Have you adjusted any of your cache sizes based on current utilization?

Answer (score -1):

No real requirement except for having in-proc session management and thus sticky sessions on the load balancer.